# Can you change lstinline without changing the global lstset?

Tags: formatting, listings

Consider that I want to be able to write:

`\inline{some code or keyword}` and just have it distinguished from the rest of the paragraph text, I've done that like this:

```
\def\inline{\lstinline[basicstyle=\ttfamily]}
```

However, if you have a custom `\lstset` that sets for instance `keywordstyle`, this will be used for the inlining as well! Is there a way to remove that? Is it possible to use something like `\lstnewenvironment` to accomplish it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can override `keywordstyle` on a case-by-case basis in `\lstinline`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor}
\lstset{keywordstyle=\sffamily\color{red},language=C}
\def\inline{\lstinline[basicstyle=\ttfamily,keywordstyle={}]}

\begin{document}
Compare \lstinline|int a=3;| with red sans-serif keywords to
\inline{int a=3;} where keywords inherit from basicstyle.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice! How about if you have more `keywordstyle`s, this wont work: `\def\inline{\lstinline[basicstyle=\ttfamily,keywordstyle={},keywordstyle=[1]{}]}`. Then is when I've defined `morekeywords`.

Answer (score 11):

Another option, is to use `\lst@ifdisplaystyle\ ... \fi` to define different `keywordstyle`'s for `lstinline` and `lstlisting`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor}
\makeatletter
\lstset{
    language=C,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\lst@ifdisplaystyle\color{blue}\fi,
    commentstyle=\color{gray}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
int a=3; // blue keyword in a lstlisting evironment
\end{lstlisting}

Inline listings are still black: \lstinline{int a=3;}.

\end{document}
```

[image]